# DocPad generate pages without extension

Tags: docpad

Is there any way to configure DocPad generate pages without extension, so hosting as static site in url it will look like: http://mysite.com/page1/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but in a different way.

The [cleanurls plugin](http://docpad.org/plugin/cleanurls) when generated for a static environment (so `docpad generate --env static`) will output say `pages/welcome.html` as `pages/welcome/index.html` which accomplishes what you're after - which is you can access `pages/welcome` in your browser no worries. Document URLs will also be updated to reflect this.

The issue of just outputting `pages/welcome` without the extension is that then the server is not aware of the mime type of the file which the browser often needs to know how to process the file correctly.

Comment: Is there any plugin to define custom URL for the page. Ex.: page is inside /posts/2012-01-01-first-post.html.md and it should be viewed through /2012/01/01/first-post/ ?

Comment: Just define `url: /2012/01/01/first-post/` in it's meta data. However, the clean urls plugin does not yet support custom urls on the static environment, this will be fixed soon: https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-cleanurls/issues/2

Comment: That issue with clean urls and custom urls is now fixed (v2.4.0)